# Provide multiple implementations for a Clojure protocol

Tags: clojure

I have a namespace that exposes common data-related functions (`get-images`, `insert-user`). I then have two database backends that have those same functions and implement them differently. They implement the interface as it were.  Each backend is contained within a namespace.

I can't seem to be able to find a good solution on how to accomplish this.

I tried dynamically loading the `ns` but no luck.  Once you do `(:require [abc :as x])`, the `x` isn't a real value.

I tried using `defprotocol` and `deftype` but that's all kinds of weird because the functions in the `deftype` need to be imported, too and that messes everything up for me.

Is there some idiomatic solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why protocols are not sufficient?

In ns data.api:

```
(ns data.api)
(defprotocol DB
  (get-images [this]) 
  (insert-user [this]))
```

In ns data.impl1:

```
(ns data.impl1
  (:require [data.api :refer :all]))

(defrecord Database1 [connection-params]
  DB
  (get-images [_] ...)
  (insert-user [_] ...))
```

Same thing in ns data.impl2.

Then when you go to use a particular db, just create the correct record:

```
(ns data.user
  (:require [data.api :refer :all])
            [data.impl1 :refer (->Database1)])

(defn use-db []
  (let [db1 (->Database1 {})]
    (get-images db1)))
```

Comment: FWIW, it seems like the preferred way to use records/types from another namespace is by `import`ing them, i.e. `(:import [data.impl1 Database1])` inside of the `(ns data.user ...)` https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/ILPz4QOEod8

Comment: @DaveYarwood: Is it? That thread doesn't really suggest that to me. It's just one guy who's doing it that way and is wondering why that approach requires underscores instead of dashes.

Comment: That thread likely predates Clojure 1.4. As of 1.4, defrecord causes the creation of a positional (eg ->Database1) and map (eg map->Database1) constructors, which are the preferred way to construct new records. When using those there is no need to import the underlying record class, just refer in the constructor function itself.

Comment: You're right, I was just going about it the wrong way somehow. This is perfect. Thanks