# When are protocol implementation created?

Tags: class, clojure, protocols, classloader

I've got a problem understanding how protocols works in Clojure. More specifically I *think* that my problem is related as to *when* classes are generated (?).

I managed to reproduce my issue with the simple following case. I have three files:

**core.clj**

```
(ns so.core
  (:require [so.soproto :refer :all])
  (:import  [so.soimpl AImpl])
)

(defn -main [] (println "Hello, World!"))
```

**soproto.clj**

```
(ns so.soproto)

(defprotocol A
  (do-smth [this]))
```

**soimpl.clj**

```
(ns so.soimpl
    (:require [so.soproto :refer :all]))

(deftype AImpl
    []
  A
  (do-smth [this] (println "whatever")))
```

Now if I try to "`lein run`", I get this:

```
$ lein run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: so.soimpl.AImpl
```

I can reproduce the issue from Emacs using the following procedure:

- open *core.clj*
- call Emacs' *cider-jack-in*
- switch cider's REPL to the namespace *so.core*
- *cider-eval-buffer*

Surely enough I get the same exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: so.soimpl.AImpl
```

Now I can "fix" the problem from within Emacs by doing this:

- switch to buffer *soimpl.clj*
- *cider-eval-buffer*
- switch back to *core.clj*
- *cider-eval-buffer* -> now things do work fine

So how can I get "`lein run`" to work? And how can I, from cider / Emacs, do a *cider-eval-buffer* on only *core.clj* without needing to open / eval the file containing the protocol implementation?

Comment: please do edit my question to fix terminology errors : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are importing a class, it needs to be compiled first. Add `:aot [so.soimpl]` to the `defproject` options in lein's project.clj.

Note, however, you do not really need to AOT compile / import AImpl to use it. Just `refer` in its constructor instead.

<strike>`(:import  [so.soimpl AImpl])`</strike>

`(require [so.soimpl :refer (->AImpl)])`

See this recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22258384/1756702).

Comment: thanks for your help... I'm not familiar with the "dash / superior" -> thinngy in the require :refer.  What does it do differently than, say, ":refer :all"? (let say AImpl is the only thing I declare in *so.soimpl*)?

Comment: The `->AImpl` is just a factory function created automatically for you when you did `(deftype AImpl ...)` in the `so.soimpl` namespace.